# Como trabalhar com o Scheduled condicional?

Tags: java, scheduler

Esse cara é o Scheduled, ele é accionado quando o projeto é executado. Assim como ele está se encontra no automático. Gostaria de invés de estar no automático ser accionado somente quando for chamado, alguém tem uma ideia de como poderia fazer isso?

```
@Scheduled(cron="*/50 * 02-23 ? * *")  // 10 em 10 segundos executa das 02:00 horas até as 23:00 (23:59) 
public void processarJOB() {
        System.out.println("inicio processarJOB --> processando: "  + new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
        Locale.setDefault(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
        try {
            if(!executandoJob) {
                executandoJob = true;
                processarPrestacao();
                executandoJob = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            executandoJob = false;
            logger.error("" , e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você quer ativar o agendamento após uma ação do usuário por exemplo? É isso?

Comment: Positivo, é isso mesmo, eu encontrei algo parecido, mas ainda não entendo como adaptar ao contexto do meu código.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406713/how-to-conditionally-enable-or-disable-scheduled-jobs-in-spring

Comment: Cara, eu sei que dá de fazer exatamente isso e eu vou precisar disso também, então vou pesquisar. Se eu encontrar a solução eu posto aqui.